# What might be the reason my Toshiba Satellite L875D-S7332 laptop's fan is running so much?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, fan, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba L875D-S7332 laptop came with Windows 8, and when the free updates for Windows 8.1 and 10 came, I took them.

It is becoming very bothersome how much the fan runs. When I make webcam calls, the people I am talking with are always hearing the fan. (I can wear a headset, but I want to solve the problem.)

I notice that the fan certainly gets louder when there's intense activity on the CPU, but it also does at times when there isn't much going on. Additionally, it's moderately loud nearly all the time.

I'd guess this has been going on for at least half a year, maybe a whole year, or maybe as long as Windows 10 has been out.

I've boosted the back of the computer, so that the air can flow better around the fan, but that does not seem to make any difference.

Is this maybe a problem with the BIOS? If it is (or isn't) how might I approach this problem and solve it?

Comment: Clean all the fluff out of your computer. Replace the CPU thermal paste.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have noticed the multitude of Windows processes and Background processes running in Windows 10. While I don't think they often account for the fan running, I would like to understand exactly what each is doing and how I could control whether they automatically start or not. (When I first installed Windows 10, one of my first priorities was to kick Cortana out, but while it never burdens my eyes in the desktop, I still haven't succeeded to banish it from background processes that automatically start.)

Comment: That's too broad a question to be asking.

Comment: I can't dispute that. Blue but true.